# build an instance via has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what I think is a simple structure:

```
class GroupEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :title, :description, :identifier, :start_date, :end_date, :time_zone, :url, :capacity, :info_url, :logo_url, :logo_ssl_url, :status

  has_one :event_venue
  has_one :event_organizer
  has_one :event_ticket
  has_one :event_condition
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  has_many :group_events
  ...
end
```

But in the Rails console when I execute

```
@user = User.new
@event = @user.group_events.build
```

I get an error: ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for group_events (:user in GroupEvent).

Update: I still can't get the user and the GroupEvent to see each other. GroupEvent.new and EventVenue.new create new objects, and

```
@event = GroupEvent.new
@venue = @event.build_event_venue
```

creates an @event.event_venue object, as it should. (Though  I'm still confused that

```
@event.event_venue.build
```

returns a NoMethodError: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass.)

Comment: What about `@user.build_group_event`?

Comment: I get a "no method error". It really doesn't seem to be drawing any type of association between the two. Even @user.group_events.nil? returns the same inverse association error. 

@ event = GroupEvent.new successfully creates an event.

Thank you for your prompt response @KyleDecot. It's my first time asking on Stack, and I missed seeing the comment until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It works now.

```
@event = @user.group_event.build
```

creates a new GroupEvent object. For anyone coming after, I apologize, I don't know what I did. The above code all still looks the same. I wasn't aware that I needed to restart the console each time I made a change, but restarting the console seemed to fix my problems.

A lingering question is bothering me. Both @user.build_group_event and @user.group_event.build generate the same result (a GroupEvent object), but for my other classes, @event.build_event_venue generates an object, but @event.event_venue.build still returns a "NoMethodError: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass". I just can't figure it out. But I have working code, so I'm not going to make too big a deal about it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Building associated models works differently for `has_one` and `has_many` associations. If your model `has_many :foos`, you can call `self.foos.build`.  However if it `has_one :foo`, you have to call `self.build_foo`.